# how to keep my app language without changing when changing screen orientation?

Tags: android, configuration, orientation, setlocale, onsaveinstancestate

I finished my app with multi languages , but when the device orientation is changed to landscape then app's language is changed .

can I use (onSaveInstanceState) method to keep app language without changing when rotating screen?

what is the code I have to insert ??

Comment: Could you check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your `manifest`

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
</activity>
```

And then

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // you can do something here
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        // orientation_landscape
        Toast.makeText(this, "orientation_landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        // orientation_portrait
        Toast.makeText(this, "orientation_portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```